# first countability and some totally disconnected spaces.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space that can be written as a countable union of pairwise disjoint clopen subsets. Is $X$ first countable.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: What if one of the closed subspaces is not first countable? Is that possible?

**Added:** Once you have a space $Y$ that is not first countable, you can build a space $X$ that is a countable union of pairwise disjoint closed subsets and is not first countable in a very simple way: let $X=\Bbb N\times Y$, where $\Bbb N$ has the discrete topology and $X$ the usual product topology. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $Y_n=\{n\}\times Y$: then each $Y_n$ is a clopen subset of $X$ that is homeomorphic to $Y$, so $X$ is not first countable, and the sets $Y_n$ are clearly pairwise disjoint.

For an example not built in this way, let $X$ be any uncountable set, and fix a point $p\in X$. Let

$$\tau=\{U\subseteq X:p\notin U\}\cup\{U\subseteq X:p\in U\text{ and }X\setminus U\text{ is countable}\}\;;$$

then $\tau$ is a topology on $X$, $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is a Lindelöf Hausdorff space, and every point of $X\setminus\{p\}$ is an isolated point. Let $C=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ be a countably infinite subset of $X\setminus\{p\}$, and for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $Y_n=\{x_n\}$. Let $Y_0=X\setminus C$. Then $\{Y_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a pairwise disjoint family of clopen subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$, and $X$ is not first countable at the point $p$.

Comment: ,then $X$ is not 1st countable, But am looking for an example. Still not found such space which is not 1st countable.

Comment: @Nancy: Do you know any example of any space that is not first countable?

Comment: @Brain,the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{R}$ but it cannot be written as a countable union of pairwise disjoint closed subsets!! so it doesnt help.

Comment: @Nancy: Sure it does: take the union of countably many copies of that space! For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $X_n$ be a copy of that space, chosen so that the sets $X_n$ are pairwise disjoint. Let $X=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$. Say that $U\subseteq X$ is open iff $U\cap X_n$ is open in $X_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: @Brain, $\mathbb{R}$ is the cofinite space and $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup A_n,$ where A_n are closed and pairwise disjoint subsets of $X$, so they are also of course open. $A_1^{c}$ is finite but $(A_1)^{c}$ is open so $((A_1)^{c})^{c} = A_1$ must be finite!!!

Comment: @Nancy: No, the $A_n$ need not be open. For example, $\Bbb Q$ is the countable union of the sets $\{q\}$ for $q\in\Bbb Q$, and each of them is closed but not open. In my last example above the sets $Y_n$ with $n\ge 1$ are open as well as closed, but $Y_0$ is only closed, not open.

Comment: @Brain, my bad. you are right. So I am adding an extra condition on the orginal question.

Comment: @Nancy: I’ve updated my answer: the ‘machine’ for creating examples already satisfied the new condition, and a minor modification makes the other example work as well.